# Python - Draw Bounding Box Around A Group Of Contours

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I have a code that finds and draws contours around objects that are Yellow.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab


lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100])
upper_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])

def test():
    while True:
        imgDef = ImageGrab.grab()
        image = np.array(imgDef)

        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations=1)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

        cv2.imshow('test', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Right now the output is as follows:
[image]

I wish to group contours that are in close proximity to one another and draw a bounding box around them like so:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Am I right to be looking into the scikit KMeans function to group them?

Comment: First, I do not see any yellow objects only blue/green.  To do what you want, just find the bounding boxes dimensions for the contours and if close enough (test the corners) get the min and max of all those bounding boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv2.kmeans for that. I suggest to change `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` by `cv2.RETR_TREE`. I share here a possible solution, the only problem is you need to know the number of cluster before use cv2.kmeans.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import random

lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100])
upper_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])

def get_contours_by_zones(contours, number_of_zones):
    center_points = []
    for cnt in contours:
        cx = cnt[:,0,0].mean()
        cy = cnt[:,0,1].mean()  
        center_points.append((cx, cy))
    center_points = np.array(center_points).astype(np.float32)

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    _,_,cluster_centers=cv2.kmeans(center_points, number_of_zones, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

    contour_zones = [[] for _ in range(number_of_zones)]
    for i, (cnt_x, cnt_y) in enumerate(center_points):
        tmp = cluster_centers - (cnt_x, cnt_y)  
        distances = np.sqrt( (tmp**2).sum(axis=1) )
        cluster_index = np.argmin(distances)
        contour_zones[cluster_index].append( contours[i] )

    return contour_zones

def test():
    while True:
        imgDef = ImageGrab.grab()
        image = np.array(imgDef)

        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

        kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations=1)

        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # ignore outer contour
        contour_per_zone = get_contours_by_zones(contours=contours[1:], number_of_zones=3)
        canvas = np.empty_like(image)
        canvas[...]=255
  
        for zone in contour_per_zone:
            # add the corresponding code to get xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax from zone, 
            # so you can draw the corresponding reactangle 
            # draw each zone with a different color
            cv2.drawContours(canvas, zone, -1, (random.randint(0, 256), random.randint(0, 256), random.randint(0, 256)), 3)

        cv2.imshow('test', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The `get_contours_by_zones()` function uses cv2.kmeans to assign each contour to a group.